# About making a GUI program an exe file.... (Java)

Tags: java, swing, file, executable, embedded-resource

I recently made a random sentence generator.  It reads from two files (a noun and a verb file) and uses 2 nouns from the file as a subject and an object, with a verb inbetween.  It was working as a java file, but when I followed a tutorial on wikihow to make it into an exe file (link- http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse), the program will run, but the label will not changed as specified. I have the noun and verb text files in the same folder as the exe file, so I do not understand where my fault it.  Any help is much appreciated :D

Thanks,
ArcWalrus

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.*;


public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame sentenceFrame = new JFrame("Ayy Lmao");
    JLabel subjectLabel = new JLabel();
    subjectLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    subjectLabel.setText("Have fun and have a dirty, dirty mind");
    String defaultTextField = "Enter a word here!";
    JTextField inputField = new JTextField(defaultTextField);

    sentenceFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

    String[] optionList = {"Subject", "Verb", "Object"};
    JComboBox optionBox = new JComboBox(optionList);

    optionBox.setSelectedIndex(2);
    class ComboListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            String selectedOption = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        }
    }

    ActionListener comboListener = new ComboListener();
    optionBox.addActionListener(comboListener);





    //sentencePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout);
    sentenceFrame.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);

    JButton createSentenceButton = new JButton("CREATE!");


    sentenceFrame.add(subjectLabel);
    sentenceFrame.add(inputField);
    sentenceFrame.add(optionBox);
    sentenceFrame.add(createSentenceButton);



    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            String subject;
            String verb;
            String object;
            if (inputField.getText().equals("") || inputField.getText().equals(defaultTextField)){
                String subjectNoun = findNoun();
                subject = subjectNoun.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + subjectNoun.substring(1, subjectNoun.length());
                verb = findVerb();
                object = findNoun();
                subjectLabel.setText(subject + " " + verb + " " + object + ".");
            }

            else{
                if(optionBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Subject")){
                    subject = inputField.getText().substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + inputField.getText().substring(1, inputField.getText().length());
                    verb = findVerb();
                    object = findNoun();
                    subjectLabel.setText(subject + " " + verb + " " + object + ".");
                }
                if(optionBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Verb")){
                    subject = findNoun();
                    subject.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
                    verb = inputField.getText();
                    object = findNoun();
                    subjectLabel.setText(subject + " " + verb + " " + object + ".");
                }
                if (optionBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Object")){
                    subject = findNoun();
                    subject.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
                    verb = findVerb();
                    object = inputField.getText();
                    subjectLabel.setText(subject + " " + verb + " " + object + ".");
                }
            }


        }
    }

    ActionListener listener1 = new ButtonListener();

    createSentenceButton.addActionListener(listener1);


    sentenceFrame.setSize(500, 200);
    sentenceFrame.setVisible(true);
    sentenceFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public static String findNoun(){
    /* // The name of the file to open.
    String fileName = "temp.txt";

    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }    

        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();            
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");                   
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    */
    Random random = new Random();

    String fileName = "src/Nouns.txt";

    String line = null;

    //int numNouns = 0;
    ArrayList<String> nounsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            //System.out.println(line);
            //numNouns++;
            nounsArrayList.add(line);

        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("ERROR- Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
        }
      catch(IOException ex) {
          System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
      }

    int randomNounNum = random.nextInt(nounsArrayList.size() - 1);
    return nounsArrayList.get(randomNounNum);

    }

public static String findVerb(){
    Random random = new Random();

    String fileName = "src/Verbs.txt";

    String line = null;

    //int numNouns = 0;
    ArrayList<String> verbsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            //System.out.println(line);
            //numNouns++;
            verbsArrayList.add(line);

        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("ERROR- Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
        }
      catch(IOException ex) {
          System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
      }

    int randomVerbNum = random.nextInt(verbsArrayList.size() - 1);
    return verbsArrayList.get(randomVerbNum);

    }
```

}

Comment: Why `.exe` and not a `.jar` file?

Comment: *"After having completed your project in Eclipse, your next goal will be to create a runnable version of your project. The **simplest and most standard** process for running a Java project is to run an executable file (.exe)."*  What a complete load of bull excrement!  Java apps. are designed to run on Windows, OS X & *nix.  The best way to **deploy** a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  I think they were fooled by words in that 'How To' linked in the question.  I quoted a little from the top of the how to page.

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels even as an "executable jar file" it won't work.

Comment: *"even as an "executable jar file" it won't work."*  I would *highly recommend* getting it working that way first, no matter what you intend doing.  Not only is it easier (and more x-platform) but there are more people willing to help with making executable Jars than making Windows .exe files (of Java apps. at least).

Answer (score 2):

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
```

Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.